# Get the text from a UITextView located in a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

My UITableViewController's UITableView is populated four times with a customized prototype UITableViewCell: `InfoCell *infoCell;`

The subclassed cell contains `UITextView *inputTextView;`

When `nextButtonPressed` I want to get the text from the first cell:

```
-(IBAction)nextButtonPressed:(id)sender {

NSString *firstCellText = ?
[dataSource objectAtIndex:dataIndex] setObject:firstCellText forKey:@"Texture"];
}
```

How to get the text from the textView in the first infoCell in the UITableView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is a single UITextView, why not make it a property of your View Controller.  It will get created lazily when the cell is created initially and added to your cell view hierarchy.

Then you can simply access it with self.inputTextView when the next button is pressed.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I should make the UITextView by code in the TableViewController class and then add it as a subView of the infoCell in cellForRowAtIndexPath? (Now the textView added to the prototype cell in Storyboard add connected to its property in the InfoCell class)